# 日本語に違和感: タグwiki編集ページの右に出るヘルプ

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 日本語

URL例: https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/edit-tag-wiki/70

> タグ wiki とは?
>
> タグ Wiki **抜粋**とは、タグが示すトピックをテキスト形式で簡単に紹介したものです。タグ質問リストの上部に、タグが表示されるとツールヒントとして表示されます。こちらを先に完了してください!
>
> 完全なタグ wiki とは、興味があるユーザー向けに、トピックを詳細に紹介したものです:
>
> ► どのような質問にこのタグを付けますか?
> ► 基本的な定義
> ► 主題の簡単な説明
> ► 詳細情報への重要リンク
> ► 妥当なサイズの 1 ページ
>
> 適切なタグ Wiki の書き方のアドバイスを参照してください。

- 「タグ Wiki 抜粋」「完全なタグ wiki」という用語に違和感
- 表示される場所の説明がわかりにくい
- 「主題」「妥当なサイズの 1 ページ」に違和感

英語版

> What are Tag Wikis?
>
> The tag wiki excerpt is a brief plain text introduction to the topic that the tag represents. It is shown at the top of tag question lists, and as a tooltip wherever the tag appears. Complete this first!
> The full tag wiki is a detailed introduction to the topic, suitable as a destination for those curious about it:
>
> ► what questions should have this tag?
> ► some basic definitions
> ► brief introduction to the subject
> ► important links for learning more
> ► one reasonably sized page
>
> See our advice on writing great tag wikis.

Answer (score 3):

タグ wiki の書き方

タグ wiki の**要約**は、タグが示すトピックを簡単に紹介したものです。ここでは Markdown 記法は使えません。要約は、タグ付けされた質問一覧の先頭に表示されるほか、タグのツールチップとしてあらゆる箇所で表示されます。まずはこちらを優先的に埋めましょう！

タグ wiki の**本文**は、タグが示すトピックをより詳しく紹介したものです。例えば、興味があるユーザー向けに以下のポイントをおさえておくとよいでしょう:

► どんな質問にこのタグを付ければよいですか?
► 基本的な定義
► タグが示すトピックの簡単な紹介
► もっと知りたい人向けの必見リンク
► なるべく一般的な 1 ページ分の長さにおさまるように

すばらしいタグ wiki を書くためのアドバイスもご覧ください。