# 単語の不一致: タグwiki編集ページでの抜粋と要約

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 日本語

タグWiki編集ページでの単語の不一致を発見しました。

> 抜粋
>
> [入力欄]

となっているのですが、右のタグwikiの書き方ではこうなっています。

> タグ wiki の書き方
>
> タグ wiki の**要約**は、タグが示すトピックを簡単に紹介したものです。

[以前の質問](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/135/%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E%E3%81%AB%E9%81%95%E5%92%8C%E6%84%9F-%E3%82%BF%E3%82%B0wiki%E7%B7%A8%E9%9B%86%E3%83%9A%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B8%E3%81%AE%E5%8F%B3%E3%81%AB%E5%87%BA%E3%82%8B%E3%83%98%E3%83%AB%E3%83%97)を見る限り、恐らく一部修正がされたのでしょうが、今のままでは単語が不一致な状態となっています。

この単語の不一致が私の勘違いでなければ、今後どちらに修正されるのかを教えていただきたいです。

Comment: どっちの方が適切だと思っていますか？

Comment: @jmac 要約が適切だと思っています。なぜなら、この単語が使われる部分はタグに関して簡単に紹介するため、本文から抜粋するだけでは無く要約する必要があると思うからです、

Comment: 2023年に改めて議論の上、[「要約」で統一する方向](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3920/#comment4011_3921)となりました。

Answer (score 2):

> 利用案内

とするのはどうでしょうか。

「要約」案を最初に出したのは私な気がしますが、抜粋/要約欄は、簡潔な定義を書く場所という以上に、「どういう質問に使うべきか」を書く場所としての意味合いを強調した方がよいように思いました。

Comment: Transifexでは[このストリングです](https://www.transifex.com/projects/p/stack-overflow-ja/translate/#ja/english/40286572?qt=%E3%82%BF%E3%82%B0%20wiki%20%E3%81%AE)。何入れるべきを教えてくれるか、直接直してくれませんか？