# タグwikiの用語「抜粋／要約」の統一

Tags: 討議, 完了, 翻訳, タグwiki

タグwikiにはポップアップなどに表示される短かい文が有り、[「抜粋」あるいは「要約」](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/tag-excerpts)と呼ばれています。英語サイトでは「excerpt」です。

現在、この用語は不統一で、どちらが使われるかは使用箇所により異なります。

例:

- 「要約の編集履歴」（UI要素）
- 「使い方、もしくはタグの抜粋」（UI要素）
- 「タグwikiの抜粋(要約)」（ヘルプの表現）

これを「抜粋」か「要約」のどちらかに統一したいと思います。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

「要約」で統一するのが良いと思います。

「抜粋」の字義的な意味とタグwikiでの実際の使われ方には違いが大きく、やや解りにくいです。本体の抜粋になっているとは限りません。本体が無いタグもあり、正確な表現は難しいですが、「要約」の方が素直に理解されると思います。

過去の議論でも「要約」を推奨する意見のみだと思います。

- [翻訳案：タグwikiにはどんな内容を記述すればいいですか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2847/%e7%bf%bb%e8%a8%b3%e6%a1%88-%e3%82%bf%e3%82%b0wiki%e3%81%ab%e3%81%af%e3%81%a9%e3%82%93%e3%81%aa%e5%86%85%e5%ae%b9%e3%82%92%e8%a8%98%e8%bf%b0%e3%81%99%e3%82%8c%e3%81%b0%e3%81%84%e3%81%84%e3%81%a7%e3%81%99%e3%81%8b#comment2556_2847)
- [単語の不一致: タグwiki編集ページでの抜粋と要約](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1480/%e5%8d%98%e8%aa%9e%e3%81%ae%e4%b8%8d%e4%b8%80%e8%87%b4-%e3%82%bf%e3%82%b0wiki%e7%b7%a8%e9%9b%86%e3%83%9a%e3%83%bc%e3%82%b8%e3%81%a7%e3%81%ae%e6%8a%9c%e7%b2%8b%e3%81%a8%e8%a6%81%e7%b4%84#comment398_1480)
- https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/211/

Comment: 特に反対意見がないようですので、この度「要約」で統一する方向で進めてまいりたいと思います