# 翻訳案：タグwikiにはどんな内容を記述すればいいですか？

Tags: 討議, 完了, 翻訳, タグwiki

この投稿は日本語版ヘルプページの1つ、[What should a tag wiki excerpt contain?](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/tag-excerpts) の和訳案です。
(草稿は@akiさんがチャットにて提案してくださいました、ありがとうございます！)

改善案がありましたら編集をお願いします。

---

### タグwikiの要約にはどんな内容を記述すればいいですか？

「タグ」とは、サイトで許容されているトピックを示すための手引書です（間接的には、無効なトピックをも示しています）。このため、最初の2ページのタグのwikiには優れた要約が必要です。素晴らしく完璧なタグwikiがあればそれでよいのですが、まずは要約を書くところから始めるのが簡単でしょう。要約に書かれた500文字以内の短いテキストは、タグのポップアップを含むさまざまな場所に表示されます。

### 便利なタグ要約を書くためのガイドライン

1. **"要約"ではタグを簡潔に説明する必要があります**。要約は500文字に制限されているため、タグに関連するすべてを言及する必要はありません。要約ではそのタグが付いた質問の共通の性質を定義する必要があり、短い文章で説明してください。一方、Markdownで書かれたタグwikiは長く、30,000文字以上書けます。
2. **あまりにも専門的でない限り、タグの背景にある概念の一般的な説明は避けてください**。例えば「電子メール」というタグは、電子メールが何であるかを説明するべきではありません。ほとんどのインターネットユーザーはそれが何であるかを知っているでしょうし、電子メールについての詳細な説明にはここではあまり価値がありません。
3. **タグを使用するための一般的な規則を書いてください**。つまり「このタグをどのような質問に付けるべきか？」と言うことです。タグは質問を整理することを目的としているため、タグ使用の規則が書かれていなければタグ付けがされませんしタグが不適切になってしまいます。セールストークのようであるかもしれません：「私を選んでください」と叫ぶタグでいっぱいの部屋で、あなたのタグを質問者にどうやって選ばせますか？
4. **一般的な知識のタグもあります**。たとえ3～4単語であっても、要約には少し説明が必要です。しかしタグが一般に知れ渡っている場合、つまりあなたが道で知らない人にタグ名を言って理解されるような場合、説明は不要です。あなたのコミュニティでのタグの使用方法にこだわると良いでしょう。要約の説明は日本語版コミュニティのためであることを忘れないでおきましょう。

Comment: 原文の説明では"email"タグを例にして「各Stack Exchange Networkのサイトごと [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com)、[Super User](https://superuser.com)、[Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com) で適切な説明を使い分けましょう」という項目がありますが、日本語版は現状「スタック・オーバーフロー」しか存在しないので説明としては冗長かなと思い削りました。

Comment: 「抜粋」でも間違いではないが、「要約」の方がより分かりやすいのではないか。 / 全体的に「"タグwikiの抜粋"に絞った説明」なのか「タグwikiの説明」なのかがはっきりしない印象。

Comment: 関連メタの投稿では「要約」と「本文」という言い回しをしており、こちらの方がしっくりくるかなと思います。 - https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/135/3060

Comment: cubick さん、そこを変えるのであれば、サイト内の他の記述も変えないといけないですね。たとえばタグの編集履歴のところでは「抜粋履歴」となっています。

Comment: @nekketsuuu この件に限らず、統一出来る箇所は適時修正すべきでしょう。なお「抜粋履歴」もあまりいい訳ではなく、「抜粋(要約)の編集履歴」等とした方がより親切かなと思います。

Comment: みなさま、時を経てこの度「抜粋(要約)」を「要約」に[変更するはこび](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3921/14055) となりました。こちらの投稿を編集してまいります m_ _m。

Answer (score 1):

2023年10月に、「抜粋(要約)」を「要約」に変更し、サイトへの反映を確認いたしました。

[image: ようやく、要約に ♪]