# 英語が残っている：タグ情報画面

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳

タグの前の「About」と下の編集ボタンの「Excerpt history」の2か所です。

「About」はタグの後ろに「について」とするのが日本語風でしょうが難しいかも？

「Excerpt history」の「Excerpt」は言葉からすると「抄録」でしょうが、「abstruct」系の「要旨」の方が合ってる感じがします。

■赤く下線を引いたところ
[image: タグ情報画面]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

追記@2020/09/03
@kunifさんのフィードバックコメントを受けまして「概要」と「要約の編集履歴」と入力いたしました。サイトに反映されるまで少しお待ちくださいませ。

---

[日本語版](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/tags/python/info)と[英語版](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/python/info)のタグの画面を確認し、以下の通り和訳をいくつか入力いたしました。いかがでしょうか？

**1. 「About」**
「About」をタグの後ろに移動させることはおっしゃる通り難しいです、申し訳ありません。配置を変えることが難しいので「次のタグについて : 」と入力してみました。

尚、本サイトでのAboutの使われ方を調べましたところ、どうやらこれまでは「概要」と訳されることが多かったようにみられたためそちらも入力いたしました。もちろん他に何か良い和訳案がございましたら直接Traducirに入力いただいても、こちらにご投稿いただいても、どちらでもOKです。

https://ja.traducir.win/strings/13902

**2. 「Excerpt history」**
「要旨」の方が合ってる感じがするというkunifさんの上のお言葉から、以前に@[nekketsuuu](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2847/%E7%BF%BB%E8%A8%B3%E6%A1%88-%E3%82%BF%E3%82%B0wiki%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AF%E3%81%A9%E3%82%93%E3%81%AA%E5%86%85%E5%AE%B9%E3%82%92%E8%A8%98%E8%BF%B0%E3%81%99%E3%82%8C%E3%81%B0%E3%81%84%E3%81%84%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99%E3%81%8B#comment2558_2847)さんと@[cubick](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2847/%E7%BF%BB%E8%A8%B3%E6%A1%88-%E3%82%BF%E3%82%B0wiki%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AF%E3%81%A9%E3%82%93%E3%81%AA%E5%86%85%E5%AE%B9%E3%82%92%E8%A8%98%E8%BF%B0%E3%81%99%E3%82%8C%E3%81%B0%E3%81%84%E3%81%84%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99%E3%81%8B#comment2561_2847)さんが残されたコメントを思い出し読み直しました。Transifexではある程度の履歴が確認可能で、恐らくですが、excerpt historyの e の小文字の箇所が大文字に変わり、今回英語に戻ってしまったのではないかと思われます。せっかくの機会ということで、これまで「抜粋履歴」と表記していた箇所を「抜粋(要約)の編集履歴」とするのが良いのではないかと思い、そちらを入力いたしました。

https://ja.traducir.win/strings/13581

Comment: 「概要」と「要約の編集履歴」が良いでしょう。「抜粋(要約)の...」だと少し長いし、「概要」と「要約」で関連性・統一感があるように見えるので。

Comment: それでは、[抜粋](https://ja.traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=(%3Fi)excerpt)を要約に書き換えて行く方向で動いてまいりたいと思います。